# Difference between BCS and BDC

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am confused between BCS and BDC, What I have got is: BDC exist only on SharePoint 2007,and it's the responsible for external connection ,

But in SharePoint 2010 and 2013 , BDC no more exist and its replaced by BCS. 
But in other story , I found BCS was merged with BDC to do the external connection .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Main difference:

BDC = SharePoint 2007

BCS = SharePoint 2010

There is no BDC anymore in SharePoint 2010 or 2013. And you can also say that BCS is an extension of BDC or newer version of BDC.

The Business Data Catalog (also known as BDC) existed in Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007 (MOSS, not Windows SharePoint Services) for read operations.

Business Data Connectivity (also acronym’ed BDC, though it’s now Connectivity, and it plays a very similar role) was introduced in SharePoint Foundation 2010 (also SharePoint Server 2010, of course).  This BDC’s job is to provide connectivity to back-end data systems, as was the job of the BDC (Catalog) in MOSS 2007.

However, it’s much more rich.

1. It’s in Foundation, so its capabilities are available “for free”
2. It supports read/WRITE access to data.

Also check:

http://sharepointpromag.com/sharepoint/what-difference-between-bcs-and-bdc

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2970be39-89e3-475d-aa9c-300b5880f801/bdc-vs-bcs?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious